# Disable VPN upon application exit

Tags: java, android, vpn

So I'm working for a company that requires a `VPN` in order to connect to the database server. I'm facing an issue with disconnecting programmatically from the VPN service (or disabling it) upon `onPause` / `onStop`.

In order to ensure the user is indeed connected to a `VPN`, I'm using a network listener and if the user is not connected, a dialog is being shown and navigates the user to the `VPN Settings Configuration`. Once the user connects and resumes the application, the listener recognizes the `VPN IP` and everything runs great.

My issue is that I want to disable the `VPN connection` once the user has stopped using the application. Therefore, I've been trying to search for a solution that disables the `VPN connection` without requesting the user to go to the VPN Settings again. Is there an option to toggle the VPN off programmatically without navigating to the VPN Settings page?

**Network Service:**

```java
public class NetworkSchedulerService extends JobService implements
        ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {

    private ConnectivityReceiver mConnectivityReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mConnectivityReceiver = new ConnectivityReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        registerReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        String message = isConnected ? "מחובר לרשת" : "אין חיבור פעיל לרשת";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Listener:**

```
private void scheduleJob() {
    JobInfo myJob = new JobInfo.Builder(0, new ComponentName(this, NetworkSchedulerService.class))
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setMinimumLatency(1000)
            .setOverrideDeadline(2000)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(myJob);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, NetworkSchedulerService.class));
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, NetworkSchedulerService.class);
    startService(startServiceIntent); // INTERNET LISTENER
}
```

**Dialog:**

```
public void dialogVPN() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadingSplash.this);
    builder.setMessage("Please ensure VPN Connection");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

And the **returnConnType:**

```
public String returnConnType() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String result = "None";
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
            Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
            if (capabilities == null) {
                result = "None";
            }
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                result = "WIFI";
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                result = "MOBILE";
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
                result = "VPN";
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestions as to how to solve this? A proper solution or an alternative one would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can disable the VPN settings from inside the app using an API provided by Android, as I do not know about any such APIs. However, as a workaround, you can consider doing the following.

While exiting the application (on a back button press), you can use the same listener to pop up another dialog saying the user to turn off the VPN. Hence, turning off the VPN will follow the same tasks that the user had to do while turning on the VPN.

When a user exits the application using a home button press, you might consider using a `JobScheduler` in your `onDestroy` function of the exiting activity, so that you can check if the VPN connection is alive in a background service when the application is not running and create a notification which will tell the user that, the VPN is alive. Then on clicking the notification, redirect the user to the VPN configuration settings and guide the user to turn it off.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Smart solution. Wish I could have thought of it! :)

Comment: Great to know that you liked it! Thanks. :)

Comment: Great to know that I could help. Please accept the answer if that was helpful. :)

Answer (score -1):

So thanks to @Reaz I've managed to find the proper solution for now. 
**Tested on Oreo**
In case someone else is intrested..
app

```java
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
```

AppLifecycleObserver

```java
public class AppLifecycleObserver extends MultiDexApplication implements LifecycleObserver {

    public static final String TAG = AppLifecycleObserver.class.getName();
    Notifications notif = new Notifications();
    Context mContext;

    public AppLifecycleObserver(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onEnterForeground() {
        Log.v(TAG,"FOREGROUND");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onEnterBackground() {
        Log.v(TAG,"BACKGROUND");
        notif.createVPNNotification(mContext,"VPN","Please make sure to turn VPN off");
    }
}
```

on Any activity you wish to implement @ onCreate:

```java
            AppLifecycleObserver appLifecycleObserver = new AppLifecycleObserver(this);
            ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(appLifecycleObserver);
```